# how to use command line to deploy a war to gcp

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I know we can use the maven plugin to deploy the application to GCP.  E.G

mvn appengine:deploy

But for certain reason, I would like to deploy the application not from the source code, but from artifacts repository (like Nexus).

What I want to do is to fetch the war from Nexus and use some command line to deploy the war to GCP.   Anyone know how to?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it but if you are interested in such functionality, you can use [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/), which provides private Git repositories hosted on GCP.

You can use them to [deploy in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-deploying-from-source-repositories-to-app-engine) and even [automate the process](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories).

If you need to specifically use Nexus, you could [file a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product) for App Engine.